# ASP with VBScript times out while reading a file line by line

Tags: csv, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a very basic task: Upload, save and read a CSV file and then do some additional tasks for a ASP.NET web application. It uses VBScript as the backend scripting language.

Based on a few examples and reads on what is the best way to do this, I came up with the following code on how to read a CSV file line by line:

```vb
Dim inLine, inputFile
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set inputFile = fso.OpenTextFile(fpath, ForReading)
Do While inputFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    Set inLine = inputFile.ReadLine
    Response.Write(inLine)
    Response.Write("<br/>")
Loop
inputFile.Close
```

What the issue is that every time that portion of code is running, it basically hangs for a while and eventually the script times out. Which is odd, knowing that I am testing a CSV with 4 lines, which shouldn't be that hard to read.

I already save the file in a directory from which it is opened.

What could I possibly be doing wrong or where would be best to go on ahead and debug? I did try a few other methods (not by using FileSystemObject), but every time the script hangs and times out...

**EDIT**
From testing, even a file with only a few lines creates loads and loads of line breaks, which makes me think, it is not opening the file correctly, or something else might be wrong, because there aren't as many lines as I can see line breaks.

**SOLUTION EDIT**
As odd as it might sound, changing the code to

```vb
Dim inLine, inputFile, csvFile
Set inputFile = fso.GetFile(fpath)
Set csvFile = inputFile.OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)

Do Until csvFile.AtEndOfStream
    eil = csvFile.ReadLine
    Response.Write(eil)
    Response.Write("<br/>")
Loop
```

worked just fine. The file has been read and the system is not stopping and timing out anymore. 
I consider my question answered, however if anyone has insights on "WHY", that would be appreciated and accepted as the proper answer.

Also, as much as I respect users of this community, I disagree with this question being a duplicate as it is currently marked.

Comment: If you're using VB.Net, why are you not using the rich IO classes in the `System.IO` namespace and instead opting to use the old COM FileSystemObject?

Comment: This is not vb.net

Comment: Fair enough. What is it exactly then? I am basically trying to investigate various issues for a company and what they have looks like VB Script on the webs. Is it ASP.NET? Because all of the system is written in the above manner.
I also really need to change the tags and some of the terms in my original question, so advice is really appreciated.

Comment: Probably [ASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) with [VBScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript)

Comment: Awesome, many thanks @jeroenh

Comment: So calling it simply .NET application with VBScript would be correct? 
Just trying to reach out for anyone who could advise on the question itself, not the meta of the question.

Comment: Yeah, all the interfaces, IIS manager, debug scripts and messages do not help by having words and terms of ASP and .NET all around them.

Comment: @karmalis Seeing as `inLine` is an array, it might be better to iterate over its items and write them individually. That *could* be where it is going wrong.

Comment: Also @AndrewMorton running scripts from the command line is a no go, since they work properly from the command line, whereas written in *.asp file and run through a web server, it halts and times out.
Basically printing simply inLine does exactly the same. Will change my question slightly.

Comment: `inline.ReadLine` does not return an object. Remove the `Set` keyword.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers many thanks, however that did not change the behavior. Have found some examples using `OpenAsTextStream` which the system is using, so I might use that and test and then amend my question if that is the case.

Comment: `OpenAsTextStream` and `OpenTextFile` do the same thing, only that the former opens the stream from a `File` object whereas the latter opens the stream from a path string.

Comment: However `OpenAsTextStream` worked just fine which is very peculiar...